# Increasing write speed to MicroSD on MacbookPro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, data-transfer

I am experiencing really slow write speeds on my MacBook Pro on a MicroSD from Samsung which should allow write speeds of up to 20MB/s. The current transfer rate seems to be around 3-4MB/s on HFS Journaled, and the rate was way lower when I formatted it with exFAT. I see some methods for increasing speeds on other devices like Android mobiles, which involve changing the cache, and also on OSX but only for command line processes? Is there a way to implement this when dragging files over with Finder?

Comment: Turns out I had bought a counterfeit chinese card that had poor performance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indicated write/read speeds are always higher than what you should expect from a card.

Usually, the filesystem doesn't make a difference to the RW speeds.

Do also remember that copying *many* small files is significantly slower than copying one big file due to the entries required to the FS.

If you'd like to test your write speeds with the filesystem, try

```
dd if=/dev/zero | pv -betrP -s 100M -S | dd of=/path/to/your/device/temporaryfile
```

The above command will `dd` 100 mebibytes of zeros into a file into your microSD card, and will return a speed in MiB/s.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many small files to transfer over, avoid the processing overhead the Finder imposes on file drags by using the Terminal command `cp`. Type `man cp` for all the details. Should you be using the MicroSD card as off-line archival storage for many small files, consider compressing the set of files into a zip archive, then transfer the .zip file to the card, which will copy over much faster.